# Advertising API issue :error_description=An+unknown+scope+was+requested&error=invalid_scope

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

My purpose is to download the advertising  report, but I encounter Advertising API issue on below step 4 of Authorization.
I should get the authorization code but get below screen-shot error message

> ‘error_description=An+unknown+scope+was+requested&error=invalid_scope’

rather than the authorization code .

URL:

```
https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id=YOUR_LWA_CLIENT_ID
    &scope=cpc_advertising:campaign_management&response_type=code
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_RETURN_URL
```

by the way, this account also is the seller account and has approvaled the advertising API access, what should I do, thanks!

Amazon advertising API url:enter link description herehttps://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/v2/guides/authorization

Comment: You must provide proper `&scope=` because of `invalid_scope`. Also, do you replace all these placeholders like `YOUR_LWA_CLIENT_ID` and `YOUR_RETURN_URL`?

Comment: I have replace all these placeholders,but I still get the issue,by the way,I didn't answer below question,so I have to reply the question?                                                                                                                
 question :'Hi, Thanks for your interest in the Advertising API. The API allows you to programmatically manage Sponsored Ads campaigns, ad groups, ads, keywords, bids, and budgets.This information helps to provide the best possible support.'

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the client (for that application within amazon ads) is not whitelisted for Amazon ads.

Create a support ticket requesting your app to be whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon send you a email, you need to finish the step 2 then visit the url.